# Draggable/droppable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, draggable, droppable

Trying to make img elements draggable and then droppable on an array of divs. Tried the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#img_r"+i+"c"+j).draggable( {
        start: function (event, ui) {
        },
        drag: function (event, ui) {
        }
        });

    $("#r"+i+"c"+j).droppable( {
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
});
```

The images does not respond to this at all. If I remove the outter $(function() {}); they become draggable but the droppable function stays inactive.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please consider: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  BTW, any error in console? And seems you have a typo `evnet`

Comment: Typo fixed, no changes though. The console does not respond either. Thanks for the reference, I'm new to the site (and coding) so still learning the basics. The code I'm working on is spread over multiple scripts and is very long, any way I can upload all the files and make them easily readable?